# Why i'm not able to return Self in reference type without cast?

Tags: swift

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func GetNewPerson1() -> Self {
        return Person(name: "EPR") as! Self
    }
    
    func GetNewPerson2() -> Self {
        // **Error** below: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Person' to return type 'Self'
        return Person(name: "Bella")
    }
}

let person = Person(name: "King")
```

Why i'm not able to return Person instance using 'Self' return type as similar to protocol extensions.

Comment: `return Self(name: "Bella")`?

Comment: Bro, this line also throwing compile time error !

Comment: Just add `required` before `init`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you can subclass `Person` which  means that the functions would be expected to return an instance of the subclass type. This would manifestly not be the case. For example

```
class Human: Person 
{
    var genus = "Homo"
}

let me = Human(name: "JeremyP")

let meCopy = me.GetNewPerson2() // Should return a Human
print(meCopy.genus)             // Should be legal
```

In the above example, `Self` should be `Human` but `GetNewPerson2()` actually returns a `Person`. A `Person` doesn't have a genus.

Note that there is no error on `GetPerson1` but that is because you force cast the `Person` you return to the type of the object you are copying. This will actually cause a runtime error because a `Person` cannot be cast to a `Human`

```
let meCopy = me.GetNewPerson1() // Will abort
print(meCopy.genus)             // Never gets here
```

Comment: Got this scenario, But making the class final should solve this problem, but it's still not working.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I'd expect that to work, but it doesn't. But if your class is `final` what it the purpose of having the function return `Self` rather than `Person`?